# Database bean version conflict -(Process records in workqueue Guidewire

Tags: gosu, guidewire

I create a workqueue in BillingCenter Guidewire to process a large data, but to some records the database return a exception  "Database bean version conflict :"

Someone can help me?

How control worker to process records no process with conflict?

Regards,
Douglas Rezende

Answer (score 1):

That exception occurs when entity is Versionable and two process are changing the same "record". I think that you need add a control to findTargets method of WorkQueue, maybe a new instance of your WorkQueue is running before the last execution finish.

```
private var _lock : ReentrantLock = new ReentrantLock()
private final static var _batchProcessType = BatchProcessType.TC_JOBEXPIRE

override function findTargets(): Iterator<PolicyPeriod> {
  using( _lock ) {
    var maintenanceToolsAPI = new gw.webservice.pc.pc800.MaintenanceToolsAPI()
    if (!maintenanceToolsAPI?.getWQueueStatus(_batchProcessType.Code)?.NumActiveWorkItems != 0) {
      // ...
    }
    return {}.iterator() as Iterator<PolicyPeriod>
  }
}
```

That way validates that don't exist one execution with active items.

Comment: Great, I'll try this!

Answer (score 0):

If you distribute the load of your work queue across the cluster and you have messages changing the same entity this will happen. Guidewire 9 implements the concept of lease to get resources, you can implement a similar concept to avoid concurrency when sharing load of the work queue - keep a centralized table with records being processed (ID, Entity Type and status should be enough) and when you are finding records verify against that table that they are not being processed.